# How does one decide the probability distribution for an LLM during RLHF?

Tags: large-language-models, kl-divergence

I was looking into how KL divergence is used in LLMs to prevent reward hacking within the course [Generative AI with LLMs](https://www.coursera.org/learn/generative-ai-with-llms/supplement/JESIK/kl-divergence) on Coursera (if this redirects to the homepage, the article is on week 3). As mentioned before, they talk about the use of KL divergence as a penalty against the model generating text that makes no sense to the original prompt but maximises the reward against the 3Hs (or whichever benchmark is used).

However, from what I've seen on KL divergence, it requires 2 probability distributions (in this case, the original LLM and the RLHF trained LLM). However what probability distribution is used in this case? This is considering that the entire prompt is generated before the metrics can be evaluated.